# Trouble passing Translations resource to -xrm because of newlines

Tags: command-line, escape-characters, newlines, x-resources

It is possible to pass resources to X applications in command-line by appending them with -xrm parameters. So, if I want Xmessage background to be grey, I can issue `xmessage Hi -xrm "xmessage*background: grey"`.

Things get tricky if I want to modify event translations. On my `.Xresouces`, this

```
Xmessage*Translations:#override\
    <Key>F10:exit(-1) \n\
    <Key>q:exit(-1)
```

succeeds in setting *F10* and *q* keys to exit any Xmessage window, but I'm having trouble doing it with -xrm in command line, certainly because of the newlines and escaping backslashes.

I've tried the three following commands, but without success.

```
xmessage Hi -xrm "xmessage*Translations:#override <Key>s:exit(4)
    <Key>r:exit(3)
    <Key>p:exit(2)"

xmessage Hi -xrm "xmessage*Translations:#override\
    <Key>s:exit(4)\n\
    <Key>r:exit(3)\n\
    <Key>p:exit(2)"

xmessage Hi -xrm "xmessage*Translations:#override <Key>s:exit(4)" \
-xrm "xmessage*Translations:#override <Key>r:exit(3)" \
-xrm "xmessage*Translations:#override <Key>p:exit(2)"
```

The 3rd command only assigns the last key successfully. The others fail, although I expected the 1st to work, since it inserts a newline after *exit(4)* and *exit(3)*, as confirmed by echoing the command.

What am I missing and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put in single quotes :

```
xmessage Hi -xrm 'xmessage*Translations:#override\
    <Key>F10:exit(-1) \n\
    <Key>q:exit(-1)'
```

Otherwise, newlines get lost.